# Applying for Schengen Visa to attend a conference as a freelance web developer, but have other commercial documents

Tags: paperwork, schengen-visas, applications, conferences, moroccan-citizens

I'm a freelance web developer from Morocco, I started a small business for selling car parts 4 years ago and have legal documents ...etc, I stopped the business 1 year after and focused on freelancing which I've been doing for more than 7 years but started full time just couple of years ago. However, I still have the legal documents for selling car parts...etc

Now I have a conference invitation in Germany related to web development and the work I do as a freelancer,  I have proves of income from freelance clients, and have letter from a company I work with. My question is:
- Should I include the car parts business papers with these documents in the application or not, knowing it's completely unrelated to what I do at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: What relevance does the defunct business have to your current financial status?

Comment: @MichaelHampton the car parts business does not generate any income for me now and because it's exempted from taxes I still have the documents and didn't close or cancel completely. Currently, all my income comes from freelancing which is 3x the average employer salary here in my country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ali_k: welcome to this forum and (assuming the visum-request will be approved) welcome to Europe! According to [a checklist of the Germany embassy in Morocco](https://rabat.diplo.de/blob/1773036/950518995e57553d106d19ec3698d8fd/merkblatt-geschaeftsvisum-dienstaufenthalt-franz--data.pdf), proof of income over the past three months is required. So no, I would not include the documents of the business you had 7 years ago.